# How to filter a data array in reactjs from firestore database

Tags: reactjs, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data array that holds all my users and shows them in a list. i want to create a search bar and filter the users based on the entered account number.

i tried to accomplish this by using the filter method, but when i do so, i get an error that my data array is no longer able to accept `.map() function`

here is my code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const list = []
  const filteredList = []
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("Users").get().then((userSnapshot) => {

      userSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       
        const {powerAccount,first_name,registerDate,email,company,country,phone} = doc.data();
        setID(doc.data().usersID)
        list.push({
          usersID:doc.id,
          powerAccount:powerAccount,
          first_name:first_name,
          registerDate:registerDate,
          email:email,
          company:company,
          country:country,
          phone:phone,
        });
      });
      setData(list);
    });
  },[]);
```

function i am using in my searchfield input:

```
onChange={(e) => data.filter(account => e.target.value == account.powerAccount).map(filteredAccount => (
          //  console.log(filteredAccount)
            
            setData(JSON.stringify(filteredAccount))
          ))}
```

in my return:

```
 return (
 {
after filtering the below code stops working. how can i fix this?
                data.map((user,index) => (
                  <TableRow
                  hover
                  key={user.usersID}>
                  <TableCell>
                      <Box
                        sx={{
                          alignItems: 'center',
                          display: 'flex'
                        }}
                      >
                        <Typography
                          color="textPrimary"
                          variant="body1"
                        >
                          {user.powerAccount}
                        </Typography>
                      </Box>
                    </TableCell>
}
)
```

Comment: From what I see (I could be wrong though, I'm not a JS god), it could come from comparing `e.target.value` and `account.powerAccount` via "==" and not "===" (the former does an implicit type coercion), or from the fact that you stringify your data, meaning you have a string now instead of an array. Most likely the second is why your code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: even without stringify it does not work, because apparently it stops being an array and becomes an object. @GaëtanBoyals

Comment: Ah, I didn't read correctly. You don't have to map anything, Array.prototype.filter returns a newly created array with only the values passing the condition. Your code can be simplified to `setData(data.filter(account => e.target.value === account.powerAccount))`.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals that worked! thank you so much

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals one small problem now, is that once i type anything the data gets cleared because it is being called with the onChange method. how do i let it such that it sets the data once the two values are equal?

Comment: Regarding this issue, you could do one of two things: listening on an external 'OK' button or on a keyPress (for example, Enter) to trigger the filter, or instead of setting your data on each key stroke, as you figured, set it when the two values are equal: `onChange={(e) => {if (e.target.value === account.powerAccount) setData(data.filter(account => e.target.value == account.powerAccount))}` (sorry for the inline code)

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals it wont work because account is not yet defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realized it at first, but I made you do wrong changes in your code, so I'll write a full answer for clarity.

Since I don't have other information on your code (if and where you store the text field input in a state for example), I will propose a code based on what we have in your post.

You'll have to set 2 different arrays: One with the full data coming from your Firebase db that will be set once, and one with the filtered results.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
// the only addition I made
const [filteredData, setDilteredData] = useState([]);
// You don't need the following, you don't use it anywhere
// const filteredList = []
  
useEffect(() => {
  const list = []
  firebase.firestore().collection("Users").get().then((userSnapshot) => {

    userSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       
      const {powerAccount,first_name,registerDate,email,company,country,phone} = doc.data();
      setID(doc.data().usersID);
      list.push({
        usersID:doc.id,
        powerAccount:powerAccount,
        first_name:first_name,
        registerDate:registerDate,
        email:email,
        company:company,
        country:country,
        phone:phone,
      });
    });
    setData(list);
  });
},[]);
```

Then, use your full dataset to set a filtered array, based on your condition:

```
onChange={(e) => {
    setFilteredData(data.filter(account => e.target.value === account.powerAccount))
  }
}
```

Finally, in your return, check if the length of `dataFiltered` is greater than 0. If it is, display the filtered data, otherwise simply display the data.

Unfortunately, in your return code posted above, there are missing tags so I cannot write full code for it, but basically, what you have to do is something like this:

```
return (
  {
    filteredData.length > 0 ? (
      // do here what you did to render your data, but with filteredData instead
      // filteredData.map((user, index) => .......
    ) : (
      // else, render your data in full exactly like your posted code
      // data.map(user, index) => .......
    )

  }
);
```

You don't even need to setup a second array if you have access to `e.target.value` in a useState, as mentioned above. You could directly filter in the `return` method.